# what do metrics and indicators mean in the finance context? Like trading of MBS products

Tags: finance, quantitative

it's often heard in my daily work as a programmer in an investment bank, supporting mortgage backed securities desks (passthrough, agency cmo, cmbs, etc).

My take is that the terms describe the characteristics of the instruments. Is it used in more specific scope? For example, can we call price, coupon rate, duration, DV01, OAS "metrics" or "indicatives" of a bond? and what about those more specific to MBS products such as "prepayment rate"?

Comment: could you more precise about the context ? are you working on a asset management company ? on a trading desk of a bank ?

I think making your question more precise will give better answers

Comment: Bonds (like any other financial contracts) have characteristics which describe them as contract like their coupon rate, their maturity

for an investor or a trader, they bear risk which can measure by looking at how the price will evolve according to some moves in market parameters, it is the case of the DV01, or duration.

Comment: Guessing you mean indicators rather than indicatives. "indicative" normally means a non-binding quote.

Answer (score 1):

These are always used in a context and their meaning can change based on specific context. Broadly speaking and in market lingo:

1. **Price/Return metrics:** price, yield, Z spread, OAS, N Spread, Horizon return
2. **Risk metrics:** dv01, duration, convexity, VaR etc.
3. **Performance metrics:** CPR, CDR (prepay/default), Severity, Roll rates

On a trading floor, i have always heard, "indicative" in terms of indicative quote. That is, a client is asking for a price quote as an indication and not as a firm bid.